# YUI Lightbox not working on images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, lightbox, yui

I am using lightbox with YUI and having problems getting lightbox to work.

I have five images on the page and when I click on the first image, lightbox shows up and the image appears as expected. I click next and the second image loads up and can go back and forth between images without any problems.  I press the close button and lightbox closes.

When I click on the second image, it loads the image in the url, not in lightbox. I clicked on the third, fourth and five image and it does the same thing.

I have checked the markup and they are the same with the exception of the images.

Can anyone shed light why clicking on the first image loads up lightbox perfectly while the others don't work.

This is my call:

```
YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
    M.util.load_flowplayer();
    setTimeout("fix_column_widths()", 20);
    Y.use("moodle-mod_lightboxgallery-lightbox",function(){M.mod_lightboxgallery.init();
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="lightbox-gallery-image-container">
  <div class="lightbox-gallery-image-wrapper">
     <div class="lightbox-gallery-image-frame">
          <a class="lightbox-gallery-image-thumbnail" href="picture.JPG" rel="lightbox_gallery" style="background-image: url('picture.JPG'); width: 162px; height: 132px;" title="text"></a>
          <div class="lightbox-gallery-image-caption bottom">Test</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lightbox-gallery-image-container">
  <div class="lightbox-gallery-image-wrapper">
     <div class="lightbox-gallery-image-frame">
          <a class="lightbox-gallery-image-thumbnail" href="picture2.JPG" rel="lightbox_gallery" style="background-image: url('picture2.JPG'); width: 162px; height: 132px;" title="text2"></a>
          <div class="lightbox-gallery-image-caption bottom">Test2</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @stiemannkj1 Added html